# Cloud Functions with Firebase: signInWithEmailAndPassword is not a function

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I'm beginning writing code with **Cloud Functions with Firebase**. 
Of the functions below, testCreateUserAccount succeeds. 
testLogin fails with a Type Error at runtime, stating "*signInWithEmailAndPassword is not a function*"

From what I have seen in the documentation, **createUser** is under the same class as  **signInWithEmailAndPassword**, so its not clear to me why attempting to call signInWithEmailAndPassword would fail.   Any ideas? Thanks!

```
"use strict"; 

var functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);   

exports.testCreateUserAccount = functions.https.onRequest ((req, res) => {
    var email = "joe@example.com";
    var password = "joejoe";

    admin.auth().createUser({
      email: email,
      password: password,
      disabled: false
    });
} );


exports.testLogin = functions.https.onRequest ((req, res) => {
    var email = "joe@example.com";
    var password = "joejoe";

    admin.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
} );
```

Comment: According to the documentation for Firebase Admin SDK, there is no signInWithEmailAndPassword function: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.Auth. May I ask why you are trying to log in inside a Cloud Function? There may be a different way to achieve what you want to do.

Comment: We would like to build an API that we can use from iOS, Android & Web.  When a user logs in we have common behavior that we need accomplished and we would prefer to write it only once.

Comment: Documentation such as https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/password-auth does confuse the issue of what is available from firebase-cloud functions.  This documentation seems to show signInWithEmailAndPassword called from javascript.

Comment: Yes, that is the documentation for the web client. The Firebase Admin SDK is server-side, and offers some different functionality as a result. I see what you're saying about how it would be convenient to have one location for the code across platforms. However, creating a user and signing in should be done from the client.

Comment: createUser works fine from Firebase cloud functions

Comment: Yup! createUser can be useful for using third party authentication, like in this example using Instagram authentication: https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/d8eca09e7f3a45ae2d01de2fe99deafe50aca5a9/instagram-auth. If it's really important to use createUser for your desired purpose, you certainly can. Just remember to return a response because the client will not know if the user was successfully created.

Comment: It would be very useful for us to abstract signing in as well. Our requirements allow us to use firebase auth today, but its possible the requirements can change in the future.  It would be great have an API that could be the pipeline of all authentication and if we have to change the logic we can do so in our cloud functions, rather have to make sure each client user has updated their software.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! While I'm not certain how this would work logistically, it helps to know what our developers need so we can find a way to make it work. If you get a chance, please fill out a feature request: https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/

Comment: @MaryRogers In Cloud Functions you use the Firebase Admin SDK to perform administrative tasks, such as creating user accounts. The Admin SDK itself runs with administrative permissions, so it doesn't need to sign in. When the users of your app log in, you should call `signInWithEmailAndPassword()` in the client-side code of the app, not in the Cloud Function.

Comment: Is there a way to get a notification on when a user signs in so that we can send email and/or push notification to users when their account is logged in?

Answer (score 2):

You used `admin.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)` on server side, you must use it on client side.

Answer (score 0):

Now you could use the identitytoolkit's rest endpoint:

https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signUp?key=[API_KEY]

Here you have the documentation:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth/

Comment: Please don't just post some tool or library as an answer. At least demonstrate [how it solves the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605) in the answer itself.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Identity toolkit REST API like this then response with idToken. IdToken can be use to verify an account using `admin.auth().verifyIdToken(idToken)` in Cloud Function.

https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithPassword?key=YOUR_PROJECT_API_KEY_THAT_ALLOWS_IDENTITY_TOOLKIT_SERVICE&email=test@gmail.com&password=samplepass&returnSecureToken=true