# Why is 'currentUser' and 'onAuthStateChanged' in firebase always null?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

## What I want to achieve

A user, who logged in or signed up should not re-login after one hour. The restriction of one hour comes from firebase authentication, if not prevented (what I try to accomplish).

## Problem

After a user is logged in via firebase authentication (signInWithEmailAndPassword) I always get `null` for `currentUser` and `onAuthStateChanged`.

## What I tried

I'm using React (v17.0.2) using 'Create React App'. On server side I'm using NodeJS (v12). The communication between both is accomplished using axios (v0.21.1)

First I tried to send the token stored in localStorage, which came from firebase (server side), back to the server. But the server tells me, that the token is no longer valid. Server side code as follows:

```js
module.exports = (request, response, next) => {
  let idToken;
  if (request.headers.authorization && request.headers.authorization.startsWith('Bearer ')) {
    idToken = request.headers.authorization.split('Bearer ')[1];
    console.log("idToken:", idToken);
  } else {
    console.error('No token found');
    return response.status(403).json({ error: 'Unauthorized' });
  }
  admin
    .auth()
    .verifyIdToken(idToken)
    .then((decodedToken) => {
      console.log('decodedToken', decodedToken);
      request.user = decodedToken;
      return db.collection('users').where('userId', '==', request.user.uid).limit(1).get();
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error('Error while verifying token', err);
      return response.status(403).json(err);
    });
};
```

After that I tried the following code on client side.

```js
handleSubmit = () => {
    const userData = {
      email: this.state.email,
      password: this.state.password
    };
    axios
      .post(firestoreUrl() + '/login', userData)
      .then((resp) => {
        console.log("token:", resp.data); //here I get a valid token
        localStorage.setItem('AuthToken', `Bearer ${resp.data.token}`);
        console.log("firebase.auth().currentUser:", firebase.auth().currentUser); //but this is null
      })
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
        console.log("firebase.auth().currentUser:", firebase.auth().currentUser); //still null
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("Error:", error);
      });
  };
```

What irritates me is that I get a token from firebase (server side), the token is then stored in localStorage (client side) but firebase then tells me, that the currentUser is null. But presumably they are not mutually dependent =/.

I'm able to access all secured sites in my app. I can log out and in again. But whatever I do the currentUser is null.
I also tried to run the code above in `componentDidMount()`-method. But no success.

I tried an approach from this [link](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/why-is-my-currentuser-null-in-firebase-auth-4701791f74f0) (hopefully in a way it should be), but it didn't work. Still getting `null` for both `currentUser` and `onAuthStateChanged` if I implement following code.

```js
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
  if (user) {
    console.log("state = definitely signed in")
  }
  else {
    console.log("state = definitely signed out")
  }
})
```

I always get logged to the console, that the user is 'definitely signed out'.

During research I noticed that the point at which I should try to get the currentUser-Status is kind of tricky. So I guess that one solution is to implement the currentUser-code at another/the right place. And here I'm struggling =/.

Comment: After further investigation I found out, that if I run `signInWithEmailAndPassword` function on server side I stick with the issue. But if I run it on client side I get an user object from `onAuthStateChanged`. Now, I'm wondering why. And how should I handle that situation if I want the signIn function remaining on server side.

Comment: Or is it best practice to perform `signInWithEmailAndPassword` on client side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I found out at a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44532818/cloud-functions-with-firebase-signinwithemailandpassword-is-not-a-function) here on SO, I did a bad mistake. Apparently, it's not a good idea to perform the signIn- or createUser-functionality on server side. This should be done on client side. In the question mentioned above are some good reasons for doing that on server side but in my case it's quite ok to run it on client side.

Thanks to Frank van Puffelen for leading the way (see one of the comments in the question mentioned above).